# Insert a new Edge to graph in ArangoDB

Tags: graph, insert, arangodb

I'm using Arangodb 3.1.25. I need to do some testing on inserting an edge in the collection edges. I tried

```
Insert {_from : "s1" , _to :"s2", property:12}
```

but it is not working.

Error:

> Query: edge attribute missing or invalid (while executing)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have add the name of edge collection at the end.

```
Insert {_from : "s1" , _to :"s2", property:12} in collectionName
```